# Clarification regarding the fit operations present in pyspark mllib algorithms

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I had a small doubt regarding the ML operations in Pyspark.

Is the fit operation in Pyspark, a distributed operation/processing or the whole fit operation gets executed on a single node.

Details: I am trying to fit a KMeans algorithm on a huge dataset but it is taking a long time. Thus wanted a bit of clarity on the same.

PS: I am new to Pyspark, thus please excuse if you find the question silly

Comment: It is distributed. What is your environment?

Comment: I am using a EC2 linux instance with Pyspark 3.0, Java 1.8 and Python 3.5. I can see a concurrent lock on all the executors. There is a concurrent lock on all the executors
Details of the code I am using can be seen at 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763148/pyspark-hangs-at-this-point-info-blockmanagerinfo-removed-broadcast-157-piece0

Comment: In my experience, I have used AWS EMR to run pyspark jobs. I am assuming EC2 is a single instance.

Comment: Yes it is a single instance, with 16 cores and 64 GB ram.

Comment: Distributed computing would mean that you need multiple instances. Currently you are running a standalone instance of Pyspark

Comment: So, if i have 16 cores on the driver. I can see only 1 core being maxed out on the single instance. other cores are not utilized.. can i do something to change this behaviour